# Thoughtworks Cruise: Unit Testing?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, continuous-integration, thoughtworks-go

I'm evaluating Cruise (NOTE! Not CruiseControl but Cruise (commercial)) for doing CI with an unmanaged MSVC++ 2008 project. I use GoogleTest framework for my unit test. I know that GTest can output its result as an JUnit XML or XML format. My question is, does Cruise support JUnit/XML format?

How would Cruise know whether or not my unit test fail?

More information from Thoughtworks [here](http://studios.thoughtworks.com/cruise-continuous-integration/1.2/help/concepts_in_cruise.html):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, yes it does support the JUnit xml format.  See the bottom of the page.  Second to last section called "Publishing tests"

http://studios.thoughtworks.com/cruise-continuous-integration/1.2/help/managing_artifacts_and_reports.html

Answer (score 1):

Another option for when your test results are large or ugly is to translate the results into html (by xslt for example) then include the html as a new tab on the cruise build.  We do this with ncover to good effect.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worthwhile asking the Cruise guys at http://community.thoughtworks.com/hives/df92e43957/summary